# loaded content using ajax gets lost?

Tags: php, ajax

I am using AJAX to load content from mysql database when I CLICK on LINKS.

once I load the content successfully, I refresh the container every 5 seconds so the new content will be displayed.

the content gets loaded fine and the refresh part works fine too.

but the issue that I have is that when the refresh happens, the loaded content gets lost.

by "it gets lost" i mean that it will display the LAST result from the mysql database.

so, to help you understand the situation I will explain it further:

Lets say I have **3** results stored in mysql database.

I create `<a></a>` from each result in mysql using PHP. i am doing this without any issue.

1. I click on the link 2. (works fine)
2. the content of the link 2 will load on the page using AJAX. (works fine)
3. The container of content will refresh every 5 seconds. (works fine)
4. **(THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS)**  once the refresh happens, the content of link 3 will be displayed even though I haven't clicked on the link 3!

so basically, for some strange reason, the content of the last Link or last mysql result will be displayed at all time which is un-wanted. I need to load the content of the CLICKED link and make it stay until another Link is clicked.

I hope I haven't confused you. :)

here is my html code:

```
    <div id="chattercontent" style="width:90%; height:150px; resize:none; border:solid 1px #ccc; background:#F2EDF0; overflow:scroll; text-align:left;"></div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function load() {
            $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                type: "GET",
                url: "file.php?u_id=<?php echo $u_id; ?>",
                dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#chattercontent").html(response);
                    setTimeout(load, 5000)
                }
            });
        }

        load();
    });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".list-group-item").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   
    $("#chattercontent").load(this.href);

    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

and PHP code for the links:

```
   while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
       $product_list .= "<a id='listc'  class='list-group-item' href='file.php?u_id=".$u_id."' >".$u_id."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$date_added."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='light-red-flash.gif' width='20' /></a>";
   }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

edit:

this is the code for file.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['u_id'])) {

$u_id = $_GET['u_id'];  


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE u_id='$u_id' ";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){  

             $user_message = $row["user_message"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error.";
        exit();
    }
echo $user_message;
}
?>
```

as I mentioned before, the file.php returns the result properly according to the link that have been clicked on but then it will JUMP on the last result after each refresh!

Comment: you don't need to $(document).ready twice

Comment: @Jim, is that the cause of my problem?

Comment: Whats the code in file.php?

Comment: `$('#chattercontent')` is being overwritten even when `response` is blank.

Comment: We need to see the sql statement.

Comment: Sounds like the `file.php` code is not properly returning the `$u_id`, which would indicate a problem with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the current url the user has selected:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //set url 1st time
    var currentUrl = "file.php?u_id=<?php echo $u_id; ?>";
    //variable to reference the timeout
    var timer;
    function load(url) {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned
            success: function (response) {
                $("#chattercontent").html(response);
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    load(currentUrl);
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    load(currentUrl);

    $(".list-group-item").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //update url on click
        currentUrl = this.href;
        //cancel existing timer
        clearTimeout(timer);
        load(currentUrl);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you know why the loaded url keeps flashing back and forth between the last one and the one is clicked on? basically when i click on one of the links, it gets loaded but then it keeps flashing back and forth and it keeps load the last one and then loads the one i clicked on!

Comment: @shell probably because you where raking up multiple timers, some set with the old value. I have updated my answer to clear existing timer when clicking a link. I also wrapped the settimeout parameter in an anonymous function, as i should have done that in the 1st place

Comment: AMAZING. WORKED A TREAT.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't loading your dynamic content with the javascript function. Check out the following, hope it will fix your problem.

```
function load(href) {
      $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
          type: "GET",
          url: href,
          //url: "file.php?u_id=<?php echo $u_id; ?>", <-- NON DYNAMIC CONTENT
          dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
          success: function (response) {
              $("#chattercontent").html(response);
              setTimeout(function() {
                  load(href);
              }, 5000)
          }
      });
  }

  var _currentUrl;

function load(href) {
    if (!href) {
      href = _currentUrl;
    }
    $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: href,
        //url: "file.php?u_id=<?php echo $u_id; ?>", <-- NON DYNAMIC CONTENT
        dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
        success: function (response) {
            $("#chattercontent").html(response);
            setTimeout(load, 5000)
        }
    });
    _currentUrl = href;
  }
```

Comment: but using url: href will stop the refresh to work as the AJAX doesn't know which URL to reload/refresh!

Comment: see my edit, didn't check out the timeout in the success function, not sure if the scope will hold otherwise you use bind to bind the value to the timeout callback

Comment: you seem to forget the fact that AJAX will still need to know which href to load! your code doesn't indicate that you are telling the AJAX to load this URL or that URL etc etc!! href could be anything on a page!

Comment: i dont think you understand it correctly yourself, i posted another example that might make it a bit clearer

Comment: what is _currentUrl ?

Comment: what you need to do to fix your problem is save the url that is loaded at that moment (which on is clicked last), so if you introduce a global variable named _currentUrl and set _currentUrl to the last page link, you can make sure the content of that page is loaded each time

Comment: I still have difficulty to understand what the global variable would do in my case! as I said, the AJAX call would still need to know which URL to refresh every 5 seconds but in your code you are not telling it to load any URL! you are just putting href = _currentUrl; in the AJAX call which doesn't do anything! IT DOES NOT REFRESH THE CONTENT EVERY 5 SECONDS.

Comment: okay if it doesn't refresh the content every 5 seconds, your ajax call won't come in the success callback, try the error callback or check your network tab in chrome's console. Also try to put some console.logs everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused. I would be glad if you would explain it a bit more with some examples.
Anyway from what I could get from your text is that, the previous result is being overwritten.
In order to stop that, as we do while making a chatbox, you need to add the response "after" the previous result as in -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* A variable to hold the last response */
    var lastResponse = "";

    $(document).ready(function () {

        function load() {
            $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                type: "GET",
                url: "file.php?u_id=<?php echo $u_id; ?>",
                dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
                success: function (response) {
                    /* Check if it is the same response or not */
                    if (lastResponse != response)
                    {
                         /* Save the last response */
                         lastResponse = response;

                         /* Add content after the previous */
                         $("#chattercontent").html($("#chattercontent").html()+response);
                    }
                    setTimeout(load, 5000)
                }
            });
        }

        load();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. the previous results always get overwritten by the last result in the mysql database. as for your code, it will loop and loop and loop for ever and it still overwrites the results with the last result from mysql database.

Comment: @shell - I've updated it with a last response check. Tell me if I am going towards the right direction of your problem.

If its possible could you show us some screen-shots of what exactly is happening?

Comment: we are getting close now. the issue that I am having is that all the results are displayed in #chattercontent all at the same time. so the results from link1 , link2 , link3 etc will be displayed in the #chattercontent at the same time.